# Jenkins JNLP port exposes internal ip

Tags: jenkins, jnlp

We have configured our Jenkins server to use a fixed port and JNLP 4.
Our info sec team has flagged that if one were to open a web browser pointing at the JNLP port, the internal properties below are listed which includes the internal ip of the Jenkins server.

Jenkins-Agent-Protocols:
Jenkins-Version:
Jenkins-Session:
Client:
Server:
Remoting-Minimum-Version:

Is this information necessary? Is this something which can be suppressed?

Answer (score 0):

From the source: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/TcpSlaveAgentListener.java

It looks like there is no mechanism to turn it off, and according to the comments, it seems to be only for testing:

```
String header = new String(head, Charsets.US_ASCII);
if (header.startsWith("GET ")) {
    // this looks like an HTTP client
    respondHello(header,s);
    return;
}

// otherwise assume this is AgentProtocol and start from the beginning
```

(...)

```
/**
 * Respond to HTTP request with simple diagnostics.
 * Primarily used to test the low-level connectivity.
 */
private void respondHello(String header, Socket s) throws IOException {
```

(...)

If infosec requires you to turn this off, you might need to open a support ticket with cloudbees.

Comment: See [Jenkins Security](https://jenkins.io/security/) for reporting a security issue for Jenkins.